# Reliable way to install chromium or Firefox webdriver on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with Raspbian Stretch running on it. I am appending the hardware and OS details. I have some Python applications that I need to run on it. My applications need a Selenium webdriver (any browser - Firefox or Chromium preferably) to be running. I searched all over the place. After several hours of hunting, I cant seem to find a place where I can get the **geckodriver** or **chromedriver** binary for RaspberryPi Zero so I can download and get my application going.

Would really appreciate it if anyone can give me either instructions or pointers to places where reliable documentation exists.

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : 9000c1
Serial      : 00000000be8ab3b5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

This works on 32 bit raspberry pi arm OS. Even though it installs chromium as the browser, it embeds chromedriver, so launch as if it were chrome not chromium. If you use RSelenium (in R rather than python or java) you can launch using my `pineium` R package extremely easily:

```
if(!require("remotes")){install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("nbarsch/pineium")
library(pineium)

#SIMPLEST POSSIBLE LAUNCH 
remDr <- lit(browser="chrome")

#OPTIONALLY RUN HEADLESS
remDr <- pineium::lit(browser="chrome",headless=TRUE)
```

https://github.com/nbarsch/pineium